# Currency formatting not working in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, currency-formatting

The currency formatter is not working in ASP.Net MVC. The input field in the UI is showing a blank in the field when there is a value of 100.00 in the Model.ClientLicense.Rate variable.

FYI - Model.ClientLicense.Rate is a decimal value

Here is the razor code

```
<input name="Rate" type="number" class="form-control" value=@(string.Format("{0:C}", Model.ClientLicense.Rate) ) >
```

solution - changed type="number" to "text"

Comment: The value attribute **must** be in quotes.

Comment: I had to change the type to text.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this,  I always  use it when i need to show currency format hope it works to you.

```
 @(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", Convert.ToDouble(Model.ClientLicense.Rate)))
```

also I think the type attribute of the input might affect, try changing the type to text